# I have a problem when I try to use a variable from a getStringArrayListExtra()

Tags: java, android

When I use getStringArrayListExtra() to transport a variable from SecondActivity to the MainActivity, and when I use the variable, my app always crash. This is the code where there is a problem :

in MainActivity :

```
List<String> maSuperlist= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag");
    System.out.println(maSuperlist);
    //TextView DisplayList;
    //DisplayList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayListt);
    //DisplayList.setText(maSuperlist.toString());
    CharSequence[] testlist= maSuperlist.toArray(new CharSequence[maSuperlist.size()]);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),testlist,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

in SecondActivity :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);

    ArrayList tag = new ArrayList();

    EditText edit;
    Button button;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = edit.getText().toString();
            tag.add(name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button button2;
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Button button3;
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retourgameActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(retourgameActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thank you so much for your help !

EDIT:

This is the error log (logcat):

```
021-06-24 15:43:16.734 11451-11451/fr.apprentissage.version2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: fr.apprentissage.version2, PID: 11451
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.apprentissage.version2/fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:158)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
```

Comment: Please show error logs so it will be more easy to understand problem

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited my post to add the logcat

Comment: Working on your code.Please wait

Comment: What does this line print? `System.out.println(maSuperlist);`, "null"?

Comment: Yes I have a problem with a null super list finally I found it : ("cannot resolve textlist"

List<String> maSuperlist= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag");
        //TextView DisplayList;
        //DisplayList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayListt);
        //DisplayList.setText(maSuperlist.toString());
        if (maSuperlist!= null) {
            CharSequence[] testlist = maSuperlist.toArray(new CharSequence[maSuperlist.size()]);
        }
        else {

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),testlist.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

You are starting MainActivity from SecondActivity without any extras.

```
     button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retourgameActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

           //add arraylist here in intent

          retourgameActivity .putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
            startActivity(retourgameActivity);
        }
    });
```

//in your second activity ,make sure you have extras in intent.

```
if(getIntent!=null && getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag")!=null){
    List<String> maSuperlist= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag");
    System.out.println(maSuperlist);
    //TextView DisplayList;
    //DisplayList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayListt);
    //DisplayList.setText(maSuperlist.toString());
    CharSequence[] testlist= maSuperlist.toArray(new CharSequence[maSuperlist.size()]);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),testlist,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating an arraylist and before populating list you are sending it to your MainActivity.So you are passing null list to MainActivity. You should pass your list to other activity on button click.

Just do this inside your button3 listener:

```
Intent retourgameActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
retourgameActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
startActivity(retourgameActivity);
```

Remove

```
retourgameActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
```

from here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
```

**Good Practices:**

Always put null check before sending arraylist to other activity and also check null before using arraylist.size() or getting some indexes of arralist.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help given ! But I have another problem. Why the intent transform my tag list in a null object?

Comment: Thanks for compliment. Don't forget to upvote and mark answer as best for appreciation and for helping others.

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but I have applied your advice to correct the null problem. I have another think that I don't understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119601/the-intent-transform-my-list-into-an-empty-list-when-it-is-transported-into-the

Comment: If it really resolve your problem then don't forget to mark answer as best to help others.