# the Intent transform my list into an empty list when it is transported into the main activity

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, my List named tag is empty after appending item in it with the button in my second activity. The intent has a bad effect in my tag, and it is finally null in the main Activity, it so confusing and I am confused !

This is my code :

My MainActivity :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HashMap<String, Integer> happy = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    happy.put("a", 10);
    happy.put("b", 3);
    happy.put("c", 88);

    happy.toString();


    List<String> lst1 = new ArrayList<>();
    lst1.add("Hello");
    lst1.add("World");
    List<String> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lst3 = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<List<String>, String> testMap4 = new HashMap<List<String>, String>();
    testMap4.put(lst1, "Def1");
    testMap4.put(lst2, "Def2");
    testMap4.put(lst3, "Def5");

    List<String> lst4 = new ArrayList<>();
    lst4.add("bonjour");
    lst4.add("toi");
    testMap4.replace(lst4, "Def1");

    TextView textView;
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(testMap4.toString());

    EditText editTextName;
    Button btnClickHere;
    TextView textName;

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    btnClickHere = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickHere);
    textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itexti);

    btnClickHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            textName.setText(name);
            name = textName.getText().toString();
        }
    });



    //Debog system pour y voir plus clair
    Button debog;
    debog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.debog);
    debog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //Debog system pour y voir plus clair

    //Debog2 system pour y voir plus clair
    Button debog2;
    debog2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.debog2);
    debog2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*public Set keySet():retourne un ensemble de clés
             * dans cette map. Cet ensemble est retourné par le map
             * donc, un chagement dans le map est reflété dans l'ensemble
             * et vice-vers-ça
             *
             */
            Set keys = testMap4.keySet();

            //obtenir un iterator des clés
            Iterator<List<String>> itr = keys.iterator();

            List<String> key;
            ////affichage des pairs clé-valeur

            Button Testons;
            Testons = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Testons);

            while (itr.hasNext()) {

                key = itr.next();
                if (key.contains(name)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Present dans:" + key + " --> La définition est " + testMap4.get(key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Absent dans:"+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
    //Debog2 system pour y voir plus clair


    //imprimer la hashtable
    Set keys = testMap4.keySet();
    Iterator<List<String>> itr = keys.iterator();
    List<String> key;

    //préparer le text view
    TextView textView2;
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        key = itr.next();
        textView2.setText("Key: "+key+" & Value: "+testMap4.get(key));
    }
    //imprimer la hashtable

    //Createur de liste

    Button btnClickHerelist;
    btnClickHerelist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickHerelist);

    btnClickHerelist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gameActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(gameActivity);
        }});

    List<String> maSuperlist= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag");
    TextView DisplayList;
    DisplayList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayListt);

    Button changeaval;
    changeaval = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeaval);

    changeaval.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tag")!=null) {
                CharSequence[] testlist = maSuperlist.toArray(new CharSequence[maSuperlist.size()]);
                DisplayList.setText(testlist.toString());
            }
            else{DisplayList.setText("petit souci");}
        }
    });
}
```

}

My SecondActivity :

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
String name;
ArrayList tag = new ArrayList();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


    EditText edit;
    Button button;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = edit.getText().toString();
            tag.add(name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
    Button button2;
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Button button3;
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retourgameActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(retourgameActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And there is no error, only the problem I Said with an empty tag above the toaster in the "if" of the main activity

Comment: help :-( i am so confused

Comment: Can you please share link of git repository of your code. So i can use that code and fix error.

Comment: Yes ! It is located in the github of my brother, (because I am helping him to code this). If you have discord I also have it https://github.com/Hectorvouloir/Projetapplication2.
Can you explain me wath did you change exactly? I can learn from you, like my teacher ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting tag list in intent on button2 click.

Replace your second activity code with this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
String name;
ArrayList tag = new ArrayList();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


    EditText edit;
    Button button;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = edit.getText().toString();
            tag.add(name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tag.toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
    Button button2;
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tag.toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Button button3;
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retourgameActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, 
            MainActivity.class);
            retourgameActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("tag", tag);
            startActivity(retourgameActivity);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much ! How do you do to be so smart ! !! ! How did you learned all that things ! I am admiring your knowledge

Comment: Thanks for compliment. Please mark the answers as best to help others in decision to choose perfect answer.